# Android - How to get a push notification when parsing a xml?

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I have a app that parses this xml:

```
 <rss version="2.0">
 <channel>
 <title>Desire ICS by Sandvold</title>
 <description>Receive notifications for new releases</description>
 <link>http://www.sandvold.as</link>
 <item>
 <title>Beta 0.1</title>
 <description>
 Cleaned up the build (seems faster) Moved back to tristans kernel -better speed and battery hopefully) Fixed sound issue Removed Darktremor apps2sd (flash it if you want) Added bootanimation Removed apps that gave errors under update Fixed wifi problems for some
 </description>
 <link>http://www.sandvold.as/Downloads/default.html</link>
 </item>
 </channel>
 </rss>
```

But how can i get a new notification when there is a new article?
I hope you understand me and that you could help me.
Gromdroid

Comment: I really don't understand the question. What do you mean by a new *article*?

Comment: @Phil Well the xml is like a rss, so there will be every week comes a new article. Do you now understand what i mean? Otherwise ask me again.

Comment: What do you mean when you say push notification, do you mean to send a mobile a message through C2DM? the posted xml doesn't look relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mellocandle suggests, [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) is the approach you need for "pushing" messages from a server to your device:

> Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) is a service that helps
>   developers send data from servers to their applications on Android
>   devices.

The alternative to this would be to have your app make requests to the server to see if there has been an update.